# Equivalent of linux 'diff' in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, diff

I want to be able to do a standard diff on two large files. I've got something that will work but it's not nearly as quick as diff on the command line.

```
A = load 'A' as (line);
B = load 'B' as (line);
JOINED = join A by line full outer, B by line;
DIFF = FILTER JOINED by A::line is null or B::line is null;
DIFF2 = FOREACH DIFF GENERATE (A::line is null?B::line : A::line), (A::line is null?'REMOVED':'ADDED');
STORE DIFF2 into 'diff';
```

Anyone got any better ways to do this?

Comment: You figure out anything better for this?  Did you look at the Pig DIFF() function?

Answer (score 4):

I use the following approaches. (My JOIN approach is very similar but this method does not replicate the behavior of diff with replicated lines). As this was asked sometime ago, perhaps you were using only one reducer as Pig [got an algorithm](https://cwiki.apache.org/PIG/faq.html#FAQ-Q%253AHowdoImakemyPigjobsrunonaspecifiednumberofreducers%253F) to adjust the number of reducers in 0.8?

- Both approaches I use are within a few percent of eachother in performance but do not treat duplicates the same
- The JOIN approach collapses duplicates (so, if one file has more duplicates than the other, this approach will not output the duplicate)
- The UNION approach works like the Unix `diff`(1) tool and will return the correct number of extra duplicates for the correct file
- Unlike the Unix `diff`(1) tool, order is not important (effectively the JOIN approach performs `sort -u <foo.txt> | diff` while UNION performs `sort <foo> | diff)`
- If you have an incredible (~thousands) number of duplicate lines, then things will slow down due to the joins (if your use allows, perform a DISTINCT on the raw data first)
- If your lines are very long (e.g. >1KB in size), then it would be recommended to use the [DataFu MD5](http://linkedin.github.com/datafu/docs/javadoc/datafu/pig/hash/MD5Base64.html) UDF and only difference over hashes then JOIN with your original files to get the original row back before outputting

### **Using JOIN:**

```
SET job.name 'Diff(1) Via Join'

-- Erase Outputs
rmf first_only
rmf second_only

-- Process Inputs
a = LOAD 'a.csv.lzo' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.LzoPigStorage('\n') AS First: chararray;
b = LOAD 'b.csv.lzo' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.LzoPigStorage('\n') AS Second: chararray;

-- Combine Data
combined = JOIN a BY First FULL OUTER, b BY Second;

-- Output Data
SPLIT combined INTO first_raw IF Second IS NULL,
                    second_raw IF First IS NULL;
first_only = FOREACH first_raw GENERATE First;
second_only = FOREACH second_raw GENERATE Second;
STORE first_only INTO 'first_only' USING PigStorage();
STORE second_only INTO 'second_only' USING PigStorage();
```

### **Using UNION:**

```
SET job.name 'Diff(1)'

-- Erase Outputs
rmf first_only
rmf second_only

-- Process Inputs
a_raw = LOAD 'a.csv.lzo' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.LzoPigStorage('\n') AS Row: chararray;
b_raw = LOAD 'b.csv.lzo' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.LzoPigStorage('\n') AS Row: chararray;

a_tagged = FOREACH a_raw GENERATE Row, (int)1 AS File;
b_tagged = FOREACH b_raw GENERATE Row, (int)2 AS File;

-- Combine Data
combined = UNION a_tagged, b_tagged;
c_group = GROUP combined BY Row;

-- Find Unique Lines
%declare NULL_BAG 'TOBAG(((chararray)\'place_holder\',(int)0))'

counts = FOREACH c_group {
             firsts = FILTER combined BY File == 1;
             seconds = FILTER combined BY File == 2;
             GENERATE
                FLATTEN(
                        (COUNT(firsts) - COUNT(seconds) == (long)0 ? $NULL_BAG :
                            (COUNT(firsts) - COUNT(seconds) > 0 ?
                                TOP((int)(COUNT(firsts) - COUNT(seconds)), 0, firsts) :
                                TOP((int)(COUNT(seconds) - COUNT(firsts)), 0, seconds))
                        )
                ) AS (Row, File); };

-- Output Data
SPLIT counts INTO first_only_raw IF File == 1,
                  second_only_raw IF File == 2;
first_only = FOREACH first_only_raw GENERATE Row;
second_only = FOREACH second_only_raw GENERATE Row;
STORE first_only INTO 'first_only' USING PigStorage();
STORE second_only INTO 'second_only' USING PigStorage();
```

**Performance**

- It takes roughly 10 minutes to difference over 200GB (1,055,687,930 rows) using LZO compressed input with 18 nodes.
- Each approach only takes one Map/Reduce cycle.
- This results in roughly 1.8GB diffed per node, per minute (not a great throughput but on my system it seems `diff`(1) only operates in-memory, while Hadoop leverages streaming disks.