# 2 Hdfs files comparison

Tags: csv, hdfs

I have 6000+ .csv files in `/hadoop/hdfs/location1` and 6100+ .csv files in `/hadoop/hdfs/location2`.

I want to compare these two hdfs directories and find the diff of files. The diff .csv files(non-similar) should be reflected in a 3rd hdfs directory(`/hadoop/hdfs/location3`). I am not sure we can use *diff command* as in unix to hdfs file system.

Any idea on how to resolve this would be appreciable.

Anshul

Comment: The diff command gives you the differences in an orderly way so content-wise you should be careful to use it in file comparison. For example let file X have three lines each having A , B , C respectively.  The second file Y has C B A. Diff will give you that files are different  but in fact contents are the same from a record point of view.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some python (perl/etc.) script to check it. Depending on your special needs and speed, you could check for file-size first. Are the filenames identical? Are the creation-dates identical etc.?

If you want to use python, check out the [filecmp module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html#filecmp.dircmp).

```
>>> import filecmp
>>> filecmp.cmp('undoc.rst', 'undoc.rst') 
True
>>> filecmp.cmp('undoc.rst', 'index.rst') 
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the below post which provides an answer on how to compare 2 HDFS files. You will need to extend this for 2 folders.

[HDFS File Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488779/hdfs-file-comparison)

You could easily do this with the Java API and create a small app:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
chksum1 = fs.getFileChecksum(new Path("/path/to/file"));
chksum2 = fs.getFileChecksum(new Path("/path/to/file2"));
return chksum1 == chksum2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below steps will solve your problem:

1. Get the list of file names which are in first location into one file
2. Get the second location files into another file
3. Find the diff between two files using unix commands
4. Whatever the diff files you found, copy those files in the other location.

I hope this helps you. otherwise let me know.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have hdfs commands to compare the files.
Check below post we can achieve by writing the PIG Program or We need to Write Map Reduce Program.

[Equivalent of linux 'diff' in Apache Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907950/equivalent-of-linux-diff-in-apache-pig)